# something wrong in pandas.Series.mean() or .apply()

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm practicing the function of `.apply()` in pandas, but something goes wrong when I use `.Series.mean()` in the function.
here is my code:

```
In[1]: column = ['UserInfo_2', 'UserInfo_4','info_1', 'info_2', 'info_3','target']
       value = [['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'],
                ['a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'],
                range(0, 11, 2),
                range(1, 12, 2),
                range(15, 21),
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
               ]
       master_train = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(column, value)))
In[2]: def f(group):
            return pd.DataFrame({'original': group,'demand':group-group.mean()})
In[3]: master_train.groupby('UserInfo_2')['info_1'].apply(f)
Out[3]:     
     demand original
0   -4.666667   0
1   -3.000000   2
2   -0.666667   4
3    0.000000   6
4    3.000000   8
5    5.333333   10
```

I am confused because the mean of `info_1` is actually 5, but from the result abrove, the mean changes from 4.666667 to 7.

What's wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think now it is clear - you count `mean` of column `info_1` (or `original`) by `groups` from column `UserInfo_2`:

```
def f(group):
    return pd.DataFrame({'original': group,
                         'groups': group.name,
                         'demand':group - group.mean() ,
                         'mean':group.mean()})

print (master_train.groupby('UserInfo_2')['info_1'].apply(f))

     demand groups      mean  original
0 -4.666667      a  4.666667         0
1 -3.000000      b  5.000000         2
2 -0.666667      a  4.666667         4
3  0.000000      c  6.000000         6
4  3.000000      b  5.000000         8
5  5.333333      a  4.666667        10
```

I think you want `mean` of column `info_1`:

```
def f(group):
    return pd.DataFrame({'original': group,
                         'demand':group - master_train['info_1'].mean(),
                         'mean':master_train['info_1'].mean()})

print (master_train.groupby('UserInfo_2')['info_1'].apply(f))
   demand  mean  original
0    -5.0   5.0         0
1    -3.0   5.0         2
2    -1.0   5.0         4
3     1.0   5.0         6
4     3.0   5.0         8
5     5.0   5.0        10
```

EDIT:

For testing is possible add `print(group)` to function `f` - it returns `Series` from column `info_1` by groups from column `UserInfo_2`:

```
def f(group):
    print (group)
    return pd.DataFrame({'original': group,
                         'groups': group.name,
                         'demand':group - group.mean() ,
                         'mean':group.mean()})

print (master_train.groupby('UserInfo_2')['info_1'].apply(f))

0     0
2     4
5    10
Name: a, dtype: int32
1    2
4    8
Name: b, dtype: int32
3    6
Name: c, dtype: int32
     demand groups      mean  original
0 -4.666667      a  4.666667         0
1 -3.000000      b  5.000000         2
2 -0.666667      a  4.666667         4
3  0.000000      c  6.000000         6
4  3.000000      b  5.000000         8
5  5.333333      a  4.666667        10
```

And if you need `mean` of all column `info_1`:

```
print (master_train['info_1'])
0     0
1     2
2     4
3     6
4     8
5    10
Name: info_1, dtype: int32

print (master_train['info_1'].mean())
5.0
```

Comment: It is `mean` of first group by `a` from `UserInfo_2` (10 + 4 + 0)/3 = 4.6666. Second `b` is (8 + 2)/2 = 5.

Comment: But what's the difference between `group`  and `master_train['info_1']`? I am confused with the fact that `original`  in the two code are the same.

Comment: I think the best is debugging, give me a minute.

Comment: Ok, please check output from `print`, is it clearer? Sorry, I rather explain per samples as per text.

Comment: Got it, thank you!! I thought `info_1` was the paramter put directly into the function f().

Comment: Super, glad can help you!

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.

Comment: Ok~ And can you tell me how to learn pandas quickly? I am reading official docs, but I think it is not efficient.

Comment: I think you can check tutorials - `http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#pandas-cookbook` or you can check books like `Python for Data Analysis`. And my own experience - it is always slower as I want. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks~I will try it.